# How to create a mask for a transparent overlay?

Tags: android, porter-duff

I have the following scenario: a Bitmap that is used as background and another Bitmap that is used as overlay which can be either 50% transparent or opaque (changeable at run time) and a third Bitmap that contains a mask for this second Bitmap. I've tried different Xfermodes configurations and drawing orders but wasn't able to find the right one.

I'm using the mask as a bitmap because I need to be able to save it between two runs of the program or between configuration changes. It is created as the user *draws* on the screen, effectively cleaning the *fog of war*.

Code snippets from by best attempt. Only thing that didn't work as I wished it did was the transparency of my mask.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    canvas.drawBitmap(mFogOfWar, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintFog);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mMaskBitmap, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintMask);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintImage);
}
```

`Paint` objects:

```
mPaintImage.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));
mPaintFog.setAlpha(127);
mPaintMask.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

This is what I get with the current configuration to be more clear:
[image: screenshot]

I'm not sure if I am going to be able to do this setting the alpha on the Paint object; if not, I don't mind another suggestion or solution for the alpha issue, preferably one where the recreation of the bitmap being used as a *fog of war* is not necessary.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get the results I want by doing the following:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintImage);
    if (mMaskBitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mFogOfWar, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintFog);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMaskBitmap, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintMask);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMaskBitmap, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintImage);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintImageSecondPass);
    }
```

`Paint` Objects:

```
mPaintImage = new Paint(); // No Xfermode here anymore
mPaintFog.setAlpha(127);
mPaintMask.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
mPaintImageSecondPass.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN));
```

But drawing the bitmaps five times seems like a waste. As this runs in an OpenGL texture due to Android hardware aceleration (I rescale the bitmaps to the highest resolution accepted by the device's GPU) and I take a lot of care in my `invalidates()` it runs surprisingly smooth on both my Nexus S and my A500, but I am not sure about other devices (project is going to be 4.0+ anyways).

But I am convinced there must be a better way to do it. I'd like a way that avoided that much overdrawn or that at least could explain to me correctly what those Xfermodes mean and that I am not overdrawing stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried a completely different approach after having some kind of an epiphany - and realized that the solution for this problem was a much simpler approach - as it usually is. And as I need only two bitmaps, I need much fewer memory to work with it.

For drawing:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintImageRegular);
if (mFogOfWarState != FOG_OF_WAR_HIDDEN) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mFogOfWar, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintFog);
}
```

The "secret" was that instead of drawing on the mask bitmap, I'm erasing the *fog of war* using another paint:

```
mFogOfWarCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mEraserPaint);
```

The only `Paint` that has an `Xfermode` is the used one for erasing:

```
mEraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
```

And for the loading and saving of my mask, I do the following:

```
private void createFogAndMask(File dataDir) {
    BitmapDrawable tile = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fog_of_war); 
    tile.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
    mFogOfWar = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageBounds.width(), mImageBounds.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    mFogOfWarCanvas = new Canvas(mFogOfWar);
    tile.setBounds(mImageBounds);
    tile.draw(mFogOfWarCanvas);   
    tile = null;

    // Try to load an existing mask
    File existingMask = new File(dataDir, getMaskFileName());
    if (existingMask.exists()) {
        Bitmap existingMaskBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(existingMask.getAbsolutePath());
        mFogOfWarCanvas.drawBitmap(existingMaskBitmap, new Matrix(), mPaintImageRegular);
        mFogOfWarCanvas.drawPaint(mMaskEraserPaint);
        existingMaskBitmap.recycle();
        System.gc();
    }
}

public void saveMask(File folder) throws IOException {
    if (!mReady || mImagePath == null) return;
    mImage.recycle();
    System.gc();
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    File savedFile = new File(folder, getMaskFileName());

    // Change all transparent pixels to black and all non-transparent pixels to transparent
    final int length = mImageBounds.width() * mImageBounds.height();        
    final int[] pixels =  new int[length];
    mFogOfWar.getPixels(pixels, 0, mImageBounds.width(), 0, 0, mImageBounds.width(), mImageBounds.height());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            pixels[i] = Color.BLACK;
        } else {
            pixels[i] = Color.TRANSPARENT;              
        }
    }
    mFogOfWar.setPixels(pixels, 0, mImageBounds.width(), 0, 0, mImageBounds.width(), mImageBounds.height());

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(savedFile);
    mFogOfWar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, output);
    output.flush();
    output.close();     
}
```